# Where can I find API access to historical options data? Paid or free?

Tags: options, historical-data

I'm looking for a company or website that provides API access to historical options data. I would prefer a provider that has a python module to access the API. Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, Did you check http://www.historicaloptiondata.com/ ?

Comment: I did run across this site, looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I work at [Quandl](https://www.quandl.com) and I've listed some of our options databases below. Our API is free to use and data can be downloaded from our site in the tool of your choice, including Python - check out: https://www.quandl.com/tools/full-list

Here are some of our options databases:

Free:

- [Chicago Board Options Exchange](https://www.quandl.com/data/CBOE)

Premium:

- [ORATS Option Volatility Surfaces](https://www.quandl.com/data/OPT)
- [US Equity Historical & Option Implied Volatilities](https://www.quandl.com/data/VOL)
- [Quantcha Option Analytics](https://www.quandl.com/data/QOA)
- [PortfolioEffect Volatility and Risk Factors](https://www.quandl.com/data/PE)
- [Goode Analytics Open Interest Ratio Surfaces](https://www.quandl.com/data/GA)
- [OptionWorks Futures Options](https://www.quandl.com/data/OWF)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I'm looking for at least OHLC data for specific tickers.